# jQuery form is not responding to correct post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

This form works as it should except for one problem, the comments are not following $postid.

Say there are 6 posts and the user comments on post 3, post 3 comment is added to post 1 instead of post 3.
In other words, the comments will only be added to the first post.

The comments need to follow each separate post and that data is located in the variable $postid. The other two variables are for users.

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'POST', 
        url: '<?php echo APP_ROOT; ?>views/layouts/ajaxtest.php', 
        data:$('#commentForm').serialize(),
        success: function(response) 
        {
            $('#commentForm').find('.form_result').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

These are the variables in php that are passed into the form.

```
<?php
   $postid = 'contains post id';
   $user = 'contains user code';
   $otheruser = 'contains other user code';
?>
```

This is the form.

```
<form id="commentForm" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
  <input id="postid" name="postid" value="<?php echo $postid; ?>" type="hidden" />
  <input name="user" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" type="hidden" />
  <input name="friend" value="<?php echo $otheruser; ?>" type="hidden" />
  <textarea name="send[mc_comment]" placeholder='Comment' rows='1'></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm();" class="postit" />
  <div class="form_result"> </div>
</form>
```

Comment: When you View Source, are the `postid` fields filled in correctly?

Comment: Its problem with your SQL Query.Post your sql query

Comment: Yes to fields filled in correctly. The query inserts the data correctly. $postid changes according to each post and is only following the first post.

Comment: How do I add $postid to function submitForm()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that you're using the same `id="commentForm"` for all your posts. IDs have to be unique within a web page. You should use a class, not an ID, for repeating blocks.

```
<form id="commentForm" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">
```

Then change the JS as follows:

```
function submitForm(form) 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'POST', 
        url: '<?php echo APP_ROOT; ?>views/layouts/ajaxtest.php', 
        data:$(form).serialize(),
        context: form, // So that success function can access the correct form
        success: function(response) 
        {
            $(this).find('.form_result').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```